# Classic ASP random date

Tags: date, asp-classic, random, vbscript

I have tried a long time to find help regarding a random date in classic ASP.
I want to create a random date between two dates.

For example: my random date must be between 2010-04-05 and 2012-04-05.

Thankful for any help!

Best Regards
Linus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use DateDiff Function and Rnd function. The Rnd function to generate a random number and then datediff to diff the days

Comment: @ulluoink - Don't you mean DateAdd instead of DateDiff?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's much easier in VBScript.

```vb
Randomize
Function RandomDate(dtmStart, dtmEnd)
    Dim dblDate
    dblDate = (CDbl(dtmStart) - CDbl(dtmEnd)) * Rnd + CDbl(dtmEnd)
    'dblDate = Int(dblDate) ' w/o time part, just date
    RandomDate = CDate(dblDate)
End Function

Response.Write RandomDate(#1985/06/10#, Now())
```

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Randomize (re-seeding the generator) should be called once per program/script session/run, never in a routine called (potentially) many times, because random generators are designed to deliver random *sequences* of numbers.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Can you please help me understand what's wrong with it again ?... (Thx for the comment)

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I've read the blog and I really didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin - You are welcome. Would you be so kind as to edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<%
Dim DDmax,DDmin,MMmax,MMmin,YYYYmax,YYYYmin

 MMmin=1
 MMmax=12

 DDmin=1
 DDmax=28

 YYYYmin=2010
 YYYYmax=2012


 Randomize

dim strTmpDate,strTmpDateYEAR,strTmpDateMONTH,strTmpDateDAY

 strTmpDateYEAR=Int((YYYYmax-YYYYmin+1)*Rnd+YYYYmin)
 strTmpDateMONTH=Int((MMmax-MMmin+1)*Rnd+MMmin)
 strTmpDateDAY=Int((DDmax-DDmin+1)*Rnd+DDmin)

 if Len(strTmpDateMONTH)=1 then
 strTmpDateMONTH="0" & strTmpDateMONTH
 end if

 if Len(strTmpDateDAY)=1 then
 strTmpDateDAY="0" & strTmpDateDAY
 end if

 strTmpDate=strTmpDateYEAR & strTmpDateMONTH & strTmpDateDAY

 if strTmpDate > "20100405" and strTmpDate < "20120405" then

 strTmpDateYEAR=Int((YYYYmax-YYYYmin+1)*Rnd+YYYYmin)
 strTmpDateMONTH=Int((MMmax-MMmin+1)*Rnd+MMmin)
 strTmpDateDAY=Int((DDmax-DDmin+1)*Rnd+DDmin)

 if Len(strTmpDateMONTH)=1 then
 strTmpDateMONTH="0" & strTmpDateMONTH
 end if

 if Len(strTmpDateDAY)=1 then
 strTmpDateDAY="0" & strTmpDateDAY
 end if

 strTmpDate=strTmpDateYEAR & strTmpDateMONTH & strTmpDateDAY

 end if
Response.write "Example A: " & strTmpDate & "<BR>"
Response.write "Example B: " & Left(strTmpDate,4) & "-" & Mid(strTmpDate,5,2) & "-" & Right(strTmpDate,2)
%>
```